# Why does Mysql query returns OK, when it is expected a negative INT from a subtraction?

Tags: mysql, casting, subquery

I'm attaching here a part of a bigger select where I'm experiencing a strange behaviour from MySQL.

In "mytable.numberOfKoalas" I have records with integer values (INT 11)

When I perfom the following query

```
SELECT B-A FROM (
            SELECT 
                (SELECT `numberOfKoalas` FROM db.mytable WHERE name="addresses") as B,  
132 A) 
as C;
```

When B>A everything works as expected, it returns my row witht the difference value int. If `B<A` it returns nothing with messages "OK".

How do I solve this?
I already tried casting functions with no success (even if I dont think a cast should be necessary due to the `numberOfKoala` field being INT), and obviously a stmt like "SELECT 12-56;" are working...

Thanks for hints

Comment: how many rows are in mytable with name='addresses' ? Love your column names by the way ! Also [edit] your question, typo dangling sentence (`If B`)

Comment: It was not a type but a problem with `<A` malicous tag :) Yes naming is bit tricky. I'll change it now.

Comment: Are you saying that when the result is a negative number, you get zero rows instead of one?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why such magic but you can use a `CASE` statement to check the values before doing the subtraction like below. Also, you cam modify your query to look little nicer.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN B > A THEN B - A ELSE A - B END AS C 
FROM (SELECT `count` AS B,  132 AS A
FROM db.mytable 
WHERE name='addresses') xx;
```

Comment: you mean to say you also discovered the same behavior?

Comment: @koalaok, NO, rather confused why such behavior. I have no means of checking it now and so said that.

Comment: I applied your "case...when " solution, it's working now.

Comment: Actually it's a possible solution. Not  the answer. Anyway if no other explanation will arise. Yours is "the answer" :-)